# how do i retrieve the original plaintext password of a hashed password

Tags: java, database

I have gone through many articles and they all dicuss/advice how to convert a plain text password in to a hashed password and store in the database.

My question is, if the plain text password is hashed and stored in the database then how do i retrieve the original plaintext password if the user forgets the password ?

Ours is not a financial application like banking which requires very high security. Also my application demands us, to some extent to, to login and check the user account. Is there any way to do this, if we start storing the passwords by hashing them?

Comment: You don't, you ask the user to change their password.

Comment: Hashing is not the same as encrypting.

Comment: There are a decent number of articles and SO questions about this or similar topics, I'll see if I can post a relevant one when I'm not on my phone. But the short response is: don't do this! Basically the password is encrypted in that manner to "prevent" reverse engineering like you described. Imagine if someone compromised your system and was able to decrypt the passwords to plain text...

Comment: Note: I wrote "encrypted" but I should have written "hashed", as the former implies two-way conversion.

Comment: thats exactly the point of hashing something. its a one-way function.

Comment: "Ours is not a financial application like banking which requires very high security" -- *every* application that takes client credentials needs the best security that you can provide. If only to protect users that choose to use the same password on your site and their bank's site. If your company gets hacked (and chances are it will), you do *not* want the potential legal liability. For that matter, you do not want the potential that a customer of your sues you for a break-in on their other account, even if you aren't hacked. -1 for unprofessionalism.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. The only way you SHOULD do this process is to reset the user's password with something else that they can remember.

When you hash the password you run plaintext through an algorithm, the result of the algorithm is then stored to the database. To check to see if the user's password is correct (at their next log on) is to run the same algorithm again and compare the output to what's stored in the database - i.e. if the hashes match then the user's password must be right.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Personally, I would avoid, if at all possible, using a site that could recover my password, because it means a hacker who accessed their hashed password file could access my account.

You give the user a facility for setting a new password, often based on an e-mail to a previously established address, or a security question and answer.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, if the plain text password is hashed and stored in the
>   database then how do i retrieve the original plaintext password if the
>   user forgets the password?

You hash the password to be **not** able to do so. Hashing looses information, the best thing you could do is to calculate a collision for the hash.

To compare the stored password, you create the hash of a given password and compare the hash with the hash stored in the database.

If the user forgets the password, create a new password for the user: create a random password, store the hash in the db and send the plain password to the user.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you used to hash your password. But typically, it's not possible.
If user forgets his password, so you give him a link to a page where he can change it, or you give him a temporary password you generate.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said "it depends"! If you have a knowledge database which contains all the hashing combination, it's possible (reverse look up).  You can find this kind of database on the internet, so it's not a good thing to use such a haching method. So, technically it's possible, and your "-1" is not relevant.

Comment: I get your point, but IMHO "depends" is not a good answer, especially in this context where I don't think the op wants to download and store billions of hashed password, rainbow tables and stuff like that.

Comment: Of course, but he can use a web service which does that. Anyway, as I said, this is not the solution. He has to use an other way.

Comment: It indeed depends on "what you used to hash your password". If for example you use function like this: `hash(String plain){return plain;}` you actually do not hash password at all. I personally worked on system where we needed the passwords in their plain form, so we stored passwords in BASE64 encrypted form instead of hash, so we were able to extract the plain form.

Comment: What you're referring to is a "rainbow table" and technically you're right you can try and use such a thing, but it only works for whatever combinations of input:key pairs have been input. The problem though is the opening sentence, which is what Enrichman is referring to; it does not depend on the "type" of hash function, the hash function is one-way by definition. It's ultimately misleading. (Sorry for delay, on my phone)

Comment: @AlexR : When I spoke about Hashing Methods, I did not mean java methods. I mean hashing method, MD5 for example (which has having a reverse look up for a long time).
But I agree with you, if you need to get the clear password (even if  no one like that), it might be encrypted instead of hashed.

Comment: @lpratlong, you are right, hash is one way transformation by definition. I just said that if you really need this you can use other transformation (for example encryption) instead and even embed this transformation into framework that can work with extended implementations of hash functions. I understand that it is "wrong" solution and even probably abuse of API, but sometimes the real life tasks cause us to use such solutions.

Comment: @AlexR : totally agree with you when saying "the real life tasks cause us to use such solutions". 
In this way, and depending on the use case of the user who posts this question, the encryption solution should be the solution he needs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't develop in Java but, usually, when we use a hash function to encrypt our password, there are just a direction. So, is not easy to take the "word" that hash means.

In this case the solution would be to allow the user to reset his password using other fields like e-mail for example.

Comment: It's not "encrypted", it's hashed. Be carefull, these are two different things :).

Comment: Sorry, you're right. In portuguese, usually, we don't take care with those terms, but you're right. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It does not work. Hashmaps are one-way maps. You should read a bit about hashmaps, what they do and why they are useful.

You cannot get your Password back from your hash value.